# Split a comma separated string into multiple columns into db - php

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help to insert comma separates strings into multiple columns into db.

My `$_POST['search']` value output. `[search] => schools,books,mobile`

How do i make an foreach or for to insert those data into db? :S

Comment: is your question about the foreach loop or about the insertion in the db?

Comment: Are you looking for the explode function or do I misunderstand?

Comment: What does your table definition look like (z.e. which columns do you have)?

Comment: i've been looking the explode function. I just don't know how to use it to insert my separates $_POST['search'] values

Comment: I see this is tagged _mysql_. Which db api are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the explode function.

```
$queries=explode(',', $_POST['search']
```

Now `$query` is an array containing the separated values. Then you do your query, but without further informations about that, I have to stop here.

Answer (score 0):

```
                    $post = $_POST['search'];
                $queries = explode( ',', $post );
                foreach( $queries as $query ) {
                    $db->Execute("INSERT INTO tags SET name = '".$query."'");
                }
```

This seems to worked for me..

I was using @klez's informations

Comment: That's multiple rows not multiple columns. Also you shouldn't put raw user input in an SQL query like that. What if the user types `php', priority = '3000`

Comment: As mentioned by Alexandre, you'll want to look into mysql_escape_string/mysql_real_escape_string, or the similarly named functions for mysqli.